# command that shows all online connections?

Tags: linux, windows, tcp, udp

I used TCPView to see all TCP and UDP endpoints in Windows. Is there any linux command/gui that has similar functionality?

Comment: Net Activity Viewer ( https://netactview.sourceforge.net/ ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, quite a lot of tools do that, and technically, you could even implement that yourself with a shell script by walking throug `/proc`. But that's not really helpful here:

The standard tool for that these days is `ss`; run it as `ss -t` to show all **T**CP connections, `ss -u` for all **U**DP connections, `ss -t -u` for both.

Add `-l` to instead of showing established connections, show **l**istening sockets.

Add `-p` to show the **p**rocess that is owning the socket.